# shell script ogr2ogr export

Tags: ogr2ogr, linux, shell

I'm writing a simple script to export postgis data to geojson.
The ogr2ogr command works well, but I'm having problems when I'm passing the parameters.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'enter country code'
read export
echo 'exporting data from $export'
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON export.geojson PG:'dbname=alamedaok user=postgres host=localhost' -sql "SELECT id_alameda, pais, geom FROM poblaciones_def WHERE pais = `$export`"
```

The problem comes in the `WHERE pais = **`$export`"**` I don't know how "insert" the variable in the sql sentence.
I've tried with '$' and with `, with no luck.

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

Bash is particular about the quote characters `` ` ``, `'` and `"`. Use double quotes to substitute the variable in a string like `"wonderful $VAR"`. Also with Bash, the convention is that variables are upper-case, and I'd avoid using `export` as a variable name since [it is a command for environment variables](http://ss64.com/bash/export.html). Consider these changes:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "enter country code: " CODE
echo "exporting data from $CODE"
SRC="PG:'dbname=alamedaok user=postgres host=localhost'"
SQL="SELECT id_alameda, pais, geom FROM poblaciones_def WHERE pais=$CODE"
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON code_$CODE.geojson $SRC -sql $SQL
```

You can also prefix the last command with `echo` to see what it is using if it needs to be debugged.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p 'Enter country code: ' EXP
echo "exporting data from $EXP"
echo ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON export.geojson PG:'dbname=alamedaok user=postgres host=localhost' -sql "SELECT id_alameda, pais, geom FROM poblaciones_def WHERE pais = '$EXP'"
```

Notes:

- `read` uses the -p parameter to set the prompt
- You used backquotes (``) in your SQL string to enclose the variable, which bash interpreted as a [command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html). Use single quotes instead ('').
- Single quotes (' ') operate similarly to double quotes, but do not permit referencing variables, since the special meaning of $ is turned off ([ref](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html)).  The single quotes in the SQL string aren't treated as quotes as they are part of the double quoted string.